# How to responsive Slider Image in a Slider

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

Hi i am using some template slider which is working fine on Desktop version. But when i using that one in mobile view its not compatible or not responsive. so i want this as a mobile and web compatiable responsive. i already tried but unable to do it by using (width: 100%; height: auto;) but till its not working so please give some solution.

Here is My Code

```
<div id="rev_slider_279_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullscreen-container" data-alias="restaurant-header" style="margin:0px auto;background-color:#474d4b;padding:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">
        <div id="rev_slider_70_1" class="rev_slider fullscreenabanner" style="display:none;" data-version="5.1.4">
            <ul>
                <li class="slider-color-schema-dark" data-index="rs-2" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="1000" data-rotate="0" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="Slide" data-description="">
                    <img src="~/img/banner/img-01.jpg" alt="image description" data-bgposition="center center" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="30000" data-ease="Linear.easeNone" data-scalestart="100" data-scaleend="120" data-rotatestart="0" data-rotateend="0" data-offsetstart="0 0" data-offsetend="0 0" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-bgfit="cover" data-no-retina style="width:100%;height:auto;">
                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme" id="slide-897-layer-7" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['top','top','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['160','120','-120','-70']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;s:2000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:300;s:300;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="1500" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 9; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 60px; line-height: 100px;text-align:center;">
                    </div>                 

                    <div class="tp-caption banner-heading-sub tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['top','top','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['280','240','10','20']" data-fontsize="['48','48','44','28']" data-lineheight="['85','85','50','50']" data-width="['1200','1000','750','480']" data-height="none" data-whitespace="normal" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1.5;sY:1.5;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;" data-start="1000" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 7; letter-spacing: 0; font-weight: 100; text-align: center; color: #ffffff">
                        EXPEDITION OF UNEXPLORED
                    </div>
                    <div class="tp-caption banner-heading-sub tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-10" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['top','top','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['340','290','70','70']" data-fontsize="['60','60','60','40']" data-lineheight="['110','110','100','60']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:[100%];s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="1000" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 8; padding-right: 10px; text-indent: 5px; font-weight: 900; white-space: nowrap;">
                        TERRITORY
                    </div>

                    <div class="tp-caption rev-btn  rs-parallaxlevel-10" id="slide-163-layer-2" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['150','160','180','150']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power3.easeOut;" data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2000;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[175%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;" data-start="1250" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-actions='[{"event":"click","action":"jumptoslide","slide":"rs-164","delay":""}]' data-responsive_offset="on">
                        <!--<a class="btn btn-banner" href="ProductList.html"></a>-->
                        <a href="#" class="search-opener btn btn-banner">
                            <span>Explore</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-index="rs-81" data-transition="slideoverup" data-slotamount="7" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="1000" data-rotate="0" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="The Menu" data-description="">
                    <img alt="image description" src="/img/banner/img-02.jpeg" data-lazyload="/img/banner/img-02.jpeg" data-bgposition="right center" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="30000" data-ease="Power1.easeOut" data-scalestart="110" data-scaleend="100" data-rotatestart="0" data-rotateend="0" data-offsetstart="0 0" data-offsetend="0 0" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina style="width:100%;height:auto;">
                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme" id="slide-897-layer1-7" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['top','top','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['160','120','-120','-70']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;s:2000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:300;s:300;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="1500" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 9; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 60px; line-height: 100px;text-align:center;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tp-caption banner-heading-sub tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['top','top','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['280','240','10','20']" data-fontsize="['48','48','44','28']" data-lineheight="['85','85','50','50']" data-width="['1200','1000','750','480']" data-height="none" data-whitespace="normal" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1.5;sY:1.5;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;" data-start="1000" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 7; letter-spacing: 0; font-weight: 100; text-align: center; color: #ffffff">
                        ADVENTURE TOUR TEMPLATE
                    </div>
                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme banner-heading-sub rs-parallaxlevel-10" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['-80','-80','-80','-60']" data-y="['top','top','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['330','280','60','60']" data-fontsize="['60','60','60','40']" data-lineheight="['110','110','100','60']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:[100%];s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="1000" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 8; padding-right: 10px; text-indent: 5px; font-weight: 300; font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">
                        of
                    </div>
                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme banner-heading-sub rs-parallaxlevel-10" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['30','30','30','20']" data-y="['top','top','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['330','280','60','60']" data-fontsize="['60','60','60','40']" data-lineheight="['110','110','100','60']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:[100%];s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="1000" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 8; padding-right: 10px; text-indent: 5px; font-weight: 900; white-space: nowrap;">
                        2016
                    </div>
                    <div class="tp-caption rev-btn rs-parallaxlevel-10" id="slide-163-layer1-2" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['150','160','180','150']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power3.easeOut;" data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2000;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[175%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;" data-start="800" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-actions='[{"event":"click","action":"jumptoslide","slide":"rs-164","delay":""}]' data-responsive_offset="on">
                        <a href="#" class="search-opener btn btn-banner">
                            <span>Explore</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li data-index="rs-71" data-transition="slideoverup" data-slotamount="8" data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="1000" data-rotate="0" data-saveperformance="off" data-title="The Menu" data-description="">
                    <img alt="image description" src="/img/banner/zoaika1.jpg" data-lazyload="/img/banner/zoaika1.jpg" data-bgposition="right center" data-kenburns="on" data-duration="30000" data-ease="Power1.easeOut" data-scalestart="110" data-scaleend="100" data-rotatestart="0" data-rotateend="0" data-offsetstart="0 0" data-offsetend="0 0" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina style="width:100%;height:auto;">
                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme" id="slide-897-layer1-7" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['top','top','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['160','120','-120','-70']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;s:2000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="opacity:0;s:300;s:300;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="1500" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 9; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 60px; line-height: 100px;text-align:center;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tp-caption banner-heading-sub tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['top','top','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['280','240','10','20']" data-fontsize="['48','48','44','28']" data-lineheight="['85','85','50','50']" data-width="['1200','1000','750','480']" data-height="none" data-whitespace="normal" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1.5;sY:1.5;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power3.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:0px;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;" data-start="1000" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 7; letter-spacing: 0; font-weight: 100; text-align: center; color: #ffffff">
                        ADVENTURE TOUR TEMPLATE
                    </div>
                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme banner-heading-sub rs-parallaxlevel-10" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['-80','-80','-80','-60']" data-y="['top','top','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['330','280','60','60']" data-fontsize="['60','60','60','40']" data-lineheight="['110','110','100','60']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:[100%];s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="1000" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 8; padding-right: 10px; text-indent: 5px; font-weight: 300; font-style: italic; white-space: nowrap;">
                        of
                    </div>
                    <div class="tp-caption tp-resizeme banner-heading-sub rs-parallaxlevel-10" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['30','30','30','20']" data-y="['top','top','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['330','280','60','60']" data-fontsize="['60','60','60','40']" data-lineheight="['110','110','100','60']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:1500;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[100%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_in="x:0px;y:[100%];s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;s:inherit;e:inherit;" data-start="1000" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-responsive_offset="on" style="z-index: 8; padding-right: 10px; text-indent: 5px; font-weight: 900; white-space: nowrap;">
                        2016
                    </div>
                    <div class="tp-caption rev-btn rs-parallaxlevel-10" id="slide-163-layer1-2" data-x="['center','center','center','center']" data-hoffset="['0','0','0','0']" data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['150','160','180','150']" data-width="none" data-height="none" data-whitespace="nowrap" data-transform_idle="o:1;" data-transform_hover="o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;s:300;e:Power3.easeOut;" data-transform_in="y:[100%];z:0;rX:0deg;rY:0;rZ:0;sX:1;sY:1;skX:0;skY:0;opacity:0;s:2000;e:Power4.easeInOut;" data-transform_out="y:[175%];s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;s:1000;e:Power2.easeInOut;" data-mask_out="x:inherit;y:inherit;" data-start="800" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-actions='[{"event":"click","action":"jumptoslide","slide":"rs-164","delay":""}]' data-responsive_offset="on">
                        <a href="#" class="search-opener btn btn-banner">
                            <span>Explore</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question as it stands is not really answerable. Please review [the guidelines for questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

hi you set media screen according to your device related to image slider heigh width and position. and another way you can used bootstrap stylesheet and bootstrap image sllider.but remember one thing you must set media screen queries large to small.@media only screen and (max-width : 1356px) {/* Styles */}@media only screen and (max-width : 1280px) {/* Styles */}@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {/* Styles */}@media only screen and (max-width : 800px) {/* Styles */}@media only screen and (max-width : 724px) {/* Styles */}@media only screen and (max-width : 667px) {/* Styles */}@media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {/* Styles */}@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {/* Styles */}@media only screen and (max-width : 467px) {/* Styles */}@media only screen and (max-width : 436px) {/* Styles */}@media only screen and (max-width : 414px) {/* Styles */}@media only screen and (max-width : 360px) {/* Styles */}
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {/* Styles */}
i hope are you understand my answer and your problem sort out